# J2me - OutofMemory in HTTP request

Tags: java, http, memory, java-me

I have a method in a j2me project in which, after 2 days of normal working, it collapses. The error presented is the following:

```
Contacting website...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   (stack trace incomplete)
```

The said method is the one used to communicate with a website. It receives a string and a mode selector (i=1 or smth else) and procedes with the request. Here's the code:

```
 void enviarPost(int i, String comando)throws IOException, IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException, ATCommandFailedException{     
      System.out.println("Contacting website...");
        if(i == 1)
            {
            url = "http://websitedummy.com.pl/index.php?IMEI=" + imeiX + "&IP=" + ipX;
            }
            //53543D303B44723D4E616F
            else
            {
            url2 = comando;             
            url = "http://websitedummy.com.pl/index.php?data={\"IMEI\":\""+imeiX+"\",\"TS\":\"20/04/13-08:31:44\",\"SER\":\""+url2+"\"}";                

            }



            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                Thread.sleep(500);
              connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

                Thread.sleep(500);
                int con = 0;
                try{
                 con = connection.getResponseCode();
                } catch (Exception e4)
                { 
                    System.out.println(e4);

                }                   
                if (con == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    System.out.println("Vamos");
                    inputstream_ = connection.openInputStream();
                    int ch;
                    while ((ch = inputstream_.read()) != -1 ) {
                        dataReceived.append((char) ch);

                    }

                    System.out.println("Atualizado.");

                    acabouatualizar=1;

                    inputstream_.close();
                    connection.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    // Connection not ok
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("EXCEÇÂO 1 - " + e);

            } finally {
                if (inputstream_ != null) {
                    try {

                        inputstream_.close();

                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        System.out.println("EXCEÇÂO 2- " + e1);
                    }
                }
                if (connection == null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Fechou conexao.");
                        connection.close();

                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        System.out.println("EXCEÇÂO 3- " + e2);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

To solve the issue i thought about clearing all the variables used in the connection. The problem is I kind of have to be almost sure what the issue is because the error will take 2 days to happen and this will cost me a great amount of time.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you provide more stack trace?

Comment: Sadly this is the only output I'm getting at the time..

Comment: There are some errors in your code. Since you have closed the inputstream and connection in finally block, you don't need to close them in the if branch. And change if (connection == null) to if (connection != null).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for point those out! Already corrected it. Still, the issue would not likely be solved by this, right?

Comment: Maybe, you can use jconsole to view the JVM states and figure out the root cause.

Comment: I strongly feel that the issue is being caused by the dataReceived object. It is a String Buffer type. Maybe clearing it would solve it? 
Yeah, I might try the JVM aswell!

Comment: Yeah @piet.t! It was a mistake. Dave Pateral pointed that out aswell, I just corrected that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what cause the `outOfMemoryError` exception, but there are ways to work with it. The root cause of this problem can refer to this:

1. there isn't enough memory in the JVM;
2. native threads aren't enough, unable to create more threads;

You can use **jconsole** to debug with this problem, which is a tool to have a look at the memory, threads, classes usage in the JVM. Besides, the exception message can point out the root cause in some cases.